# Pandas reading formulas as nan, I need the text

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have 2 excels, one of them is a template with a few columns with formulas. I made a DataFrame of both to read. I need to add the data of the other one to the template, but pandas change the formulas for "nan" values. Otherwise, if I try to add the formulas and the data, using python on another excel, the formulas just doesnt appear and Excel shows an error message that eliminate those cells.
I need to add the data from one excel to the template not changing the formulas cells.

Add all the data using python, but formulas doesnt appear.

Making a DataFrame of both excel and template, and adding the data of one, cell by cell, to the template not touching the formulas, but the DataFrame of the template, read the formulas as "nan".

Simplyfing the code:

```
#Read Excel
df_SII_r = pd.read_excel(year+'-'+month+'-'+day+"0815.xlsx") 
df_SII = pd.DataFrame(df_SII_r)

#Read Template
df_Template_r_SII = pd.read_excel('Template.xlsx', "SII.")
df_Template_SII = pd.DataFrame(df_Template_r_SII)

#Change template values for Excel values, the first column contains the formula, so I add the data from "b+1" column on
for a in range(df_SII_r.shape[0]):
    for b in range(df_SII_r.shape[1]):
        df_Template_SII.iat[a, b+1]=df_SII.iat[a,b]
        df_Template_SII.iat[a, 0] = "=IZQUIERDA(H+"str(a)"+;HALLAR("+"-"+";H+"str(a)"+;1)-1)
```

Using the last line, Excel does not show the formula, all cells are blank.

If I don't write the last line, waiting for the template read to show the formulas, its appears as "nan"

Comment: pandas doesn't understand Excel formulas.  What are you really trying to do?  If you're trying to manipulate or automate an Excel file, there are better packages to use than going through pandas.

Comment: I need to transfer formulas from one excel to another. What package do i need??

Comment: Check out `openpyxl`, or if you are on Windows, use `win32com` to control the Excel application directly.